# Openlayers feature creation issue

Tags: openlayers

I am creating a Point feature, like this:

```
const myFeature = {
    "geometry": {"coordinates": [position[0], position[1]], "type": "Point"},
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 'my-point-feature'
  }
this.geoJSONObject['features'].push(myFeature)
```

This works perfect.

But when I do this:

```
const myFeature = new Feature(new Point([position[0], position[1]]))
myFeature.setId('my-point-feature')
this.geoJSONObject['features'].push(myFeature)
```

I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: geometryReader is not a function
>       at Function._ol_format_GeoJSON_.readGeometry_ (geojson.js:78)
>       at _ol_format_GeoJSON_.readFeatureFromObject (geojson.js:382)
>       at _ol_format_GeoJSON_.readFeaturesFromObject (geojson.js:415)
>       at _ol_format_GeoJSON_._ol_format_JSONFeature_.readFeatures (jsonfeature.js:60)

Why this difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GeoJSON feature and an OpenLayers feature are different objects types, use `new GeoJSON().writeFeatureObject` and `new GeoJSON().readFeature` to convert between formats:

```
const myFeature = new Feature(new Point([position[0], position[1]]))
myFeature.setId('my-point-feature')
const gjFeature = new GeoJSON().writeFeatureObject(myFeature)
this.geoJSONObject['features'].push(gjFeature)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It helped. I think writeFeaturesObject is writeFeatureObject as we are dealing with a single object here. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, writeFeaturesObject would return a complete GeoJSON